# Can the Pebble timeline be used via Pebble.js?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-js

It's unclear whether the Timeline features are supported when using only the pebble.js approach (e.g. no C code).  Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Pebble.js to call regular PebbleKitJS functions (e.g., `Pebble.getTimelineToken`).

As far as pushing pins to the timeline, pins are pushed via the timeline Web API, which means you can use the `ajax` function to make a request to the API from within Pebble.js.